# Printing Qt floating point variable in text browser

Tags: c++, qt

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but is there a way to print a floating point variable in a Qt TextBrowser?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You could create a source containing the floating point value and then load it into the QTextBrowser. But it's not a simple textarea if that's what you mean.

Comment: So there is no way to print a float into a text browser?

Comment: It inherits from QTextEdit, so you could use something like `setHtml()` or `setPlainText()` I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution:

```
double d = 3.1415
QTextBrowser b;
b.append(QString::number(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
float f = 1.414213;
QString fStr;
fStr.setNum(f);
QTextBrowser b;
b.append(fStr);
```